# Explicit vs Implicit upgrades of Contracts & States in Corda

Tags: corda

There seems to be plenty of [information](https://docs.corda.net/upgrading-cordapps.html#id13) on explicit contracts&states upgrades, but it seems there is lack of info about implicit contract and state upgrades.

Assume that I use signature policy for contracts. How do I migrate old states to new ones if I want to use old ones also?

**UPDATE:**
I have found those [samples](https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/implicit-cordapp-upgrades) and as I understand there is no states upgrade process at all! On the contrary, all flows/states and contracts are created in backward compatible way. But intuitively, if I have 50 releases for example, does it mean that related piece of the code will contain 50 if/else for all possible old versions of the flow? Won't the code become a mess? Is there any way of somehow normalizing the states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct. As long as the old versions of data (i.e. Corda states) exist in the network, you will need to keep this conditional logic in your contract code, so that it's capable of handling states of the older format.

What you could do to mitigate this proliferation of conditional logic is:

- identify all the states of the older format. If there are any, *migrate* them to the new format, by spending them in a transaction and re-creating them with the new format. If there aren't any, move to the next step.
- perform another implicit upgrade of your contract code that does not have any functional changes besides removing the conditional logic that is not needed anymore.

Following this steps, you can gradually remove conditional logic that's not needed, simplifying the contract code gradually. But, you're essentially back to a form of explicit upgrade, which might not be very practical depending on the number of parties and states in your network.